# Moving files into folders using bash script

Tags: shell-script

I have several files like `Apple-AP01`, `Apple-AP02`, `Banana-AP05`, `Chocolate-RS33` and others in my home directory that are pulled from an ftp server. In the same home directory there are Folders like `Fruit`, `Sweet`, etc. And within these folders, there are subfolders with names like `Apple-AP01`, `Apple-AP02`, `Chocolate-RS33`, etc.

I need to run a script on my home directory such that once I have `Apple-AP01`, it knows to place it into the Fruit folder based on the "`AP`" keyword and then further place that into the `Apple-AP01` folder. and for `Chocolate-RS33`, it needs to go into the `Sweet` folder based on the "`RS`" keyword and then further into the `Chocolate-RS33` subfolder within the `Sweet` folder. I need this for all of my files. Can someone put a bash script that would work?

I've tried

```
for f in *.
do
    name=`echo "$f"|sed 's/ -.*//'`
    letter=`echo "$name"|cut -c1`
    dir="DestinationDirectory/$letter/$name"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

I think I need to use a `for` loop, but I’m not sure how to do it in bash.

Comment: for f in *.; do
    name=`echo "$f"|sed 's/ -.*//'`
    letter=`echo "$name"|cut -c1`
    dir="DestinationDirectory/$letter/$name"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done

Comment: I think I need to use a for loop but im not sure how to do it in bash

Comment: Neither `cut` nor `sed` know that apples are fruits or chocolates are sweets, so you need a mechanism to relate the files to the directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, does it do what you want.

#### First way:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr_map

arr_map=([AP]=Fruit [RS]=Sweet)

# Iterate through indexes of array
for keyword in "${!arr_map[@]}"; do
    # Search files containing the "-$keyword" pattern in the name
    # like "-RS" or "-AP". This pattern can be tuned to the better matching.
    for filename in *-"$keyword"*; do
        # if file exists and it is regular file
        if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
            destination=${arr_map["$keyword"]}/"$filename"
            # Remove these echo commands, after checking resulting commands.
            echo mkdir -p "$destination"
            echo mv -iv "$filename" "$destination"
        fi  
    done
done
```

#### Second way:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr_map

arr_map=([AP]=Fruit [RS]=Sweet)

# Iterate through all files at once
for i in *; do
    # If the file is a regular and its name conforms to the pattern
    if [[ -f "$i" && "$i" =~ [A-Za-z]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+ ]]; then
        # trim all characters before the dash: '-' from the beginning
        keyword=${i#*-}
        # trim all digits from the ending
        keyword=${keyword%%[0-9]*}

        # if the arr_map contains this keyword
        if [[  ${arr_map["$keyword"]} != "" ]]; then
            destination=${arr_map["$keyword"]}/$i
            # Remove these echo commands, after checking resulting commands.
            echo mkdir -p "$destination"
            echo mv -iv "$i" "$destination"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: @ksuzy31 Does changing to `echo mv -v "$keyword" "$destination"` do, what you want? Without the `-i` option, the `mv` command doesn't prompt before overwrite a file.

Comment: Or Hi, what if I had apple02-05group-AP05 and have multiple hyphens and i'm still just looking for if it has keyword, AP, put it in Fruit folder and then make a subfolder with the name  apple02-05group-AP05 with this inside it

Comment: @ksuzy31 I don't know. I tested both scripts on your original filenames (Apple-AP01, Apple-AP02, Banana-AP05, Chocolate-RS33) and they were working. If filenames differs from original examples, than it needed to tailor scripts for them.

Comment: @ksuzy31 `apple02-05group-AP05` this kind filenames will be a problem, because the `[A-Za-z]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+` regex mathes only to `Apple-AP01` kind. The `[A-Za-z]+-[A-Z]+[0-9]+` means - one or more letters, then dash, then one or more capital letters, then one or more digits. So, another type of filenames wouldn't conform to this pattern.

Comment: hmm I see. Do you think there's some work around with the multiple hyphens because that's kind of what I have now. BTW thank you for above. You were right, I had the name wrong. But now I have to do these multiple hyphens but what if it was all caps like APPLE02-05GROUP-AP05. Do you think you could help me with a script that would put that into Fruit folder. and like CHOCOLATE-02GROUP-RS33 into Sweet folder.

Comment: @ksuzy31 First method should work with your new filenames. Did you try it? The `APPLE02-05GROUP-AP05` should math to the `*-"$keyword"*` pattern.

Comment: @ksuzy31 If you know, that filenames always ended with the keyword and two digits, it will be better change the pattern to something like this `*-"$keyword"[0-9][0-9]`. Or, if the amount of digits in the ending is unknown, to this `*-AP+([0-9])`(one or more digits in the ending). It will shrinks the probability of a non-right filename matching, because `*-"$keyword"*` will matches, if the keyword occurs in the middle of filename, like `CHOCOLATE-AP02GROUP-RS33`. It will be moved to the `fruit`, instead of the `sweet`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you mind displaying it as I am still a little unclear. (Thank you so much for your help. I'm doing an intern project and have never done this before so I really appreciate it MiniMax)

Comment: And I get the following error: mv: failed to access 'AP': No such file or directory

Comment: @ksuzy31 In which case?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue but it now works :) Thank you! One question is is this hard to convert to a .bat file. I realized the system I have to run this on is Windows server.

Comment: @ksuzy31 The script had the bug - instead of the `mv -iv "$keyword" "$destination"` should be the `mv -iv "$filename" "$destination"` - `"$filename"` instead of `"$keyword"`. I fixed it.

Comment: @ksuzy31 Don't know about converting to `.bat`. I didn't write scripts for Windows.

Comment: Ok, i'll ask around but thank you so so so much! You are absolutely the best!

Comment: Sorry can i ask one last question. How can I automate this so it is running like all day

Comment: @ksuzy31 Like this? - [Repeat a command every x interval of time in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430382/repeat-a-command-every-x-interval-of-time-in-terminal). Also, the `cron` program may be fits to your needs. `cron` - daemon to execute scheduled commands. But, I don't competent in this area, because I didn't do it. You need googling or ask new question on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

This should cover most of what you want to do.

`sortfood.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash


# Puts files into subdirectories named after themselves in a directory.

# add more loops for more ID-criteria

for f in *AP*; do
    mkdir -p "./fruit/$f";
    mv -vn "$f" "./fruit/$f/";
done

for f in *RS*; do
    mkdir -p "./sweet/$f";
    mv -vn "$f" "./sweet/$f/";
done
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. It is pretty good and is almost what I want. I need this such that 2 things: 1. I need it so if I ever have the same name file or am updating a file, it will automatically place it in the right folder and subfolder. and 2. It will looks through all the key words and put them in the right folder and won't throw me an error if it doesn't find anything